# Formatting my url in Python, Django

Tags: python, json, django

I would like to have my uri to be encoded

```
get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup'
```

for instance if I enter  my `campaignID = 19` and the `date = 20 Juy 2017`
I would like to have my uri:

```
uri = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=19&date=20 july 2017'
```

and the result is that I cannot get my json response because it is unable to find the  correct uri.

Here is my function

```
def get_customer_action_by_target_group(self):
     payload = {"TargetGroupID": "%s" % self.TargetGroupID, "Date":"%s" % self.date,}

     if not self.TargetGroupID or not self.date:
         get_target_group_id = int(raw_input("Please provide the target Group id:"))
         get_date = (raw_input("Please provide the date as required:"))
         self.TargetGroupID = get_target_group_id
         self.date = get_date
     response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url + "?" + str(self.TargetGroupID) + "="
                         + str(self.date),
                          json.dumps(payload), "GET")
     print response, response.text, response.reason

     return response
```

Comment: You are trying to create an Django app, so where will the user enter the value for `get_date` ?

Comment: So here  is just a raw python , not a django app.. Check my code, im input the date

Comment: and is the response generated in a django app ?

Comment: yes, but i created a command for that .....

Comment: Are you sure this kind of url is defined in `urls.py` of the django app

Comment: No all my urls are variables, im just communicating via an api ..... and get a reponse back in json.

Comment: so what is the solutuon , because i can see in my url .. the values where priniting but wrongly/

Comment: Spaces are not valid in querystring items. Use `+` instead: `&date=20+july+2017`. Or, better, use a standard date form: `&date=20170720`.

Comment: Yes, i got it right. Thank you

Comment: Hi i tested it still doesnt work

Comment: Hi i tested it still doesnt work ,  this is my base url = get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=&date=' .  and this is my response URI =https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=19&date=20 july 2017 , this is my  payload = {"TargetGroupID": "%s" % self.TargetGroupID, "Date":"%s" % self.date,
                    }

Comment: response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url + self.TargetGroupID +
                                      self.date,
                                     json.dumps(payload), "GET"). Could you write a sample of code which could return this exact URI = https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=19&date=20 july 2017    Thank you